# Multithreading in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

in my controller I have a series of nested loops

```
x.downto(0)
   y.downto(0)
      z.downto(0)
```

I would like to ask whether I can split these up in multiple threads kind like

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

does in C.

I have tried to use the

```
Thread.new do
```

method but it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: MRI has GIL, so even if you start several threads, only one tread at a time will run. Try using ruby without GIL (jruby / rubinius).

Comment: Yes I ended up using jruby. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.new{
    //some function
}
```

will definitely work but in your case if you apply like

```
x.downto(0)
Thread.new {
    y.downto(0)
    Thread.new {
        z.downto(0)
    }
}
```

It creates multiple nested threads, but it should impact. I have not come across using this scenario, but i feel this could help.

Comment: thank you for the way of thought I did this way and used a mutex to protect my variables. 

`0.upto(1) do |i|
    b = Thread.new {
 0.upto(1) do |j|
    a = Thread.new {
  0.upto(1) do |k|
    m.synchronize {
       #code here      
    }
  end 
    } 
 end;
 a.priority = 2;
 a.join;
    }
end;
b.priority = 1;
b.join;`